# Deis Batch Jobs

Tags: docker, coreos, deis

Does Deis have any support for running batch jobs / ephemeral docker containers on a cron like basis?

I could just use fleet under the hood and deploy a timer unit.  Would this be recommended or does another approach exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to model cron-style jobs on Deis is to use a `clock` process type, as you would on Heroku.  See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

Comment: I was not aware Deis currently supported the full list of Heroku process types.

Answer (score 1):

Deis has no support for batch applications. Apps in Deis follow the 12-factor model and can be deployed, scaled, and have their configuration updated to create a new release. As you said, you can schedule fleet units directly should you need this behavior. However, I'm curious as to what you're trying to accomplish?